Why "document.createElement("component-selector");" creates an empty element?
So I have a component in angular
which has the selector "app-mission"
@Component({
    selector: 'app-mission',
    templateUrl: './mission.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./mission.component.css']
})

I can use this component as expected in html by simply adding <app-mission></app-mission> to any html file in the project, and get the whole component, but when I try
var element = document.createElement("app-mission");

in typescript file, it creates an empty 
<app-mission></app-mission> element.
Why does this not work?
Is there any easy way to get this working correctly in my typescript file?
Edit:
I understand now why this doesn't work like I thought it would.
See answers for a good solution.

To create component, html needs to be compiled by angular. This article should help You https://blog.angularindepth.com/here-is-what-you-need-to-know-about-dynamic-components-in-angular-ac1e96167f9e

Using document. references are not really recommended as these won't be available in cases of Web Workers or Server Side Rendering.
Loading Components Dynamically is something that you're looking for here.

First, create a Directive that exposes the ViewContainerRef:


import { Directive, ViewContainerRef } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[appContainer]'
})
export class ContainerDirective {
  constructor(public viewContainerRef: ViewContainerRef) { }
}


Then in your Parent Component where you want to create the Component manually, use ViewChild to have access to the Directive. Inject ComponentFactoryResolver, and then create the Component Factory by calling resolveComponentFactory on the instance of ComponentFactoryResolver, and pass it the component type that you want to create. Finally, call the createComponent on the ViewContainerRef instance and pass it the component factory instance.


import { Component, ViewChild, ComponentFactoryResolver } from '@angular/core';
import { MissionComponent } from './mission/mission.component';
import { ContainerDirective } from './container.directive';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Angular';
  @ViewChild(ContainerDirective) container: ContainerDirective;

  constructor(
    private componentFactoryResolver: ComponentFactoryResolver
  ) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.loadComponent();
  }

  loadComponent() {
    const componentFactory = this.componentFactoryResolver
      .resolveComponentFactory(MissionComponent);

    this.container.viewContainerRef
      .createComponent(componentFactory);
  }
}


Finally, add the MissionComponent to the entryComponents array in your AppModule


...
import { MissionComponent } from './mission/mission.component';
...

@NgModule({
  ...
  entryComponents: [MissionComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }

Here's a Sample StackBlitz for your ref.

Hmm, I use document. references because I want to use it inside a static method

the thing is that is that I don't want to add  in html at all, I want to create the element in typescript with "document.createElement("app-mission") "

@Noob, sorry for misinterpreting your question, I've updated my answer. Please check if that's what you're looking for.

I guess what I wanted to do just doesn't work because the document.createElement method just creates a new empty element, it doesn't matter if the tag name is the same as the selector of some existing component. oh well...I thought, it would create a new instance of that component, but that isn't the case.

Yeah but what you're trying to achieve is possible by injecting Dynamic Components in your template at run time. You'd understand if you have a look at the Sample StackBlitz and the answer.

how do I get the component in ts without using any container in html files?

That's not really possible I guess. Unless you use document.createElement which is something I don't really recommend.
